# Angular 8 : call external JavaScript function in a component

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I trying to call a pure JavaScript function in my header component to animate my menu; I've create menu.js file in assets folder and add it in my angular.json file like that :

```
 "scripts": [
   "src/assets/javascript/menu.js",
]
```

**menu.js**

```
function openNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "100%";
}

function closeNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
}
```

I want to ask how to implement that in my header component

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {  } from '../search-filter-form/search-filter-form.component'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-header',
  templateUrl: './header.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./header.component.sass']
})
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

**html**

```
 <div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn"
      onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_sidenav_full#
    <a href="#">Spectacles</a>
    <a href="#">Restaurants</a>
    <a href="#">Sorties</a>
    <a href="#">Questions fréquantes</a>
    <a href="#">Chèques Cadeaux</a>
    <a href="#">À propos</a>
    <a href="#">Condition de vente</a>
  </div>
  <span style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer" onclick="openNav()">&#9776;</span>
```

Comment: So many things seem to be wrong here. If you want to animate things, why not use the built-in angular animations https://angular.io/guide/animations ; also you may want to take a look at this https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction

Comment: as @Ploppy noted you should use angular inbuild animations, but you also should NEVER directly access DOM like you do it in vanila JS, there is Renderer2 for this purpuse. docs: https://angular.io/api/core/Renderer2